# Munkres section 20 exercise 10c. Prove that this is a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ consisting of all sequences $(x_1, x_2, ...)$ such that $\sum  x_i ^2$ converges. Show that $d(x, y) = [\sum _{i=0} ^\infty (x_i-y_i) ^2]^{1/2}$ is a well-defined metric on $X$.

How can I prove this? The first two conditions are trivial, but I have no idea how to prove the triangle inequality.

Comment: Show the metric comes from an inner product, and use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: But inner product is defined in finite products and so is Cauchy-Schwarz. Is it okay to apply Cauchy-Schwarz in infinite dimension?

Comment: One can apply C-S when you have an inner product.

Comment: And the set $X$ has an inner product (needs a proof though). They can be defined on spaces of all dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

First to show it is well-defined: let $x,y \in X$. So we know that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2 < \infty, \sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i^2 < \infty$$

The [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) for $\Bbb R^n$ tells us that for each $n$:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i\right)^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2$$

and the right hand side is uniformly bounded by the product of the infinite sums of squares (so finite) and it follows that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i y_i$ converges.

As also $$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i- y_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -2\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i + \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2$$ it follows that $d(x,y)$ is well-defined (we can let $n \to \infty$ in this equality and the sum defining $d$ thus converges) and that moreover $X$ is a linear subspace ($x,y \in X \to x-y \in X$ and $x \in X \to cx \in X$ is now clear).

The triangle inequality follows from the $\Bbb R^n$ version by letting $n$ go to $\infty$ again.